# How to send email in Xcode with Version 6.2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, xcode6

I have looked at various tutorials for sending email in an app using Xcode, but most of the tutorials I have tried will not work for the current version of Xcode 6.2. When I run the IOS simulator, the email view will either instantly disappear or I can't type anything in any of the fields. I made sure to update the framework to use the MessageUI.framework. I will also post the current code I am using for the app. I want to use objective C as the language, as the app I am creating is using Objective C. Does anyone know how I can implement email in the current version(6.2)?

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface IntakeViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>{

}

- (IBAction)emailClicked:(id)sender;


@end
```

.m file

```
#import "IntakeViewController.h"

@interface IntakeViewController ()

@end

@implementation IntakeViewController

- (IBAction)emailClicked:(id)sender {
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mail setSubject:@"Review"];
        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"cbailey92@gmail.com", nil];
        [mail setToRecipients:toRecipients];
        NSString *body = @"You need more passion";
        [mail setMessageBody:body isHTML:NO];
        mail.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
        [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Run Away!" message:@"You need more passion" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result) {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Failed");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Sent");
            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"Default");
            break;
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: This problem comes because you haven't configure an Email Account in your simulator. If you try this on a device it will work perfectly

Comment: How do I configure an email account in the simulator?

Comment: With the recent update to Xcode, my email code works in the simulator!